# Express serving static file: can't set headers after they are send

Tags: node.js, express

I am using the express.static built-in middleware function to serve static files, but the console prints the error: **Can't set headers after they are sent**.

here is my code, i don't know what is wrong with this

```
'use strict';

let path = require('path');
let express = require('express');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let formidable = require('express-formidable');
let routes = require('./routes');
let app = express();
let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


let db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/old-driver');

// deal with img post
app.use(formidable({
  uploadDir: path.join(__dirname, 'upload'),
  keepExtensions: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true })); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// access-control
app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,X-Requested-With");
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","PUT,POST,GET,DELETE,OPTIONS");
  res.set("X-Powered-By",' 3.2.1')
  res.type("application/json");
  res.type("jpg");
  next();
});


// set assets path, GET /assets/demo.png
app.use('/assets', express.static('upload'));

routes(app);

app.listen(port);
```

the route middleware method:

```
getAllTeachers: (req, res) => {
    Teacher.find({}, (err, teacher) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.json(teacher);
        }
    });
},
```

Even if I remove the access-contol code as shown below, still get error

```
let db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/old-driver');

// deal with img post
app.use(formidable({
  uploadDir: path.join(__dirname, 'upload'),
  keepExtensions: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true })); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// set assets path, GET /assets/demo.png
app.use('/assets', express.static('upload'));

routes(app);

app.listen(port);
```

when I request 2 existing jpg file, I also get 404 error in one jpg file
[404 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e93Z.png)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To solve this you need to use `app.use` function instead of `app.all` for mounting your middleware function. `app.use` adds the middleware function to middleware stack ensuring that they are executed in same order at which they are added.

So you need to do this :

```
app.use((req, res, next) => { //change app.all to app.use here and remove '*', i.e. the first parameter part
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,X-Requested-With");
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","PUT,POST,GET,DELETE,OPTIONS");
  res.set("X-Powered-By",' 3.2.1')
  res.type("application/json");
  res.type("jpg");
  next();
});
```

**EDIT:**

As you told in comments the above method doesn't work so what you can do is use the setHeaders method of `express.static` method to set headers before file is served like this :

```
app.use('/assets', express.static('upload', {
  setHeaders: function(res, path) {
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,X-Requested-With");
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","PUT,POST,GET,DELETE,OPTIONS");
    res.set("X-Powered-By",' 3.2.1')
    res.type("application/json");
    res.type("jpg");
  }
}));
```

Put this static file serving middleware method **above** the `app.use` so that app.use method for setting headers is not called hence the headers won't be set again.

Comment: @Rcrab I edited the post please try what I told and tell if this makes any difference